# mysql to mysqli conversion results

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am having to update MySQL to mysqli as my host is upgrading to PHP5.6

I have managed to convert and connect to the database as below

```
 $link_id = mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_user","$db_password");
 if (mysql_select_db("$db_database", $link_id));
 else
 {
         echo "connection failed.";
 }
```

converted to

```
$link_id = mysqli_connect("$db_host","$db_user","$db_password","$db_database");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
```

I cannot get the fetch results to work, can anyone help me convert the following code

```
$results = mysql_query("$select", $link_id);
while ($query_data = mysql_fetch_row($results))
{
```

Many Thanks

Comment: There is a bug in the `if ` in the first snippet. There is a semicolon after the condition that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Another issue, in the second snippet, is that you are mixing the procedural style and the object oriented style of using `mysqli`. It's better to stick with one of them. Choosing the procedural style is certainly easier while you are in the process of migrating.

Comment: @John Kilbey which hosting you are using?

Comment: thanks, I need this bit converting and don't understand procedural style, newbie to mysqli                                                                             $results = mysql_query("$select", $link_id);
while ($query_data = mysql_fetch_row($results))
{